# OpenRefine: Remove row if specific cell in this row is empty

Tags: openrefine

The input for OpenRefine is a csv file containing data like this

```
phy,205.4,,,Unterwasserakustik. Sonar-Technik,,
phy,205.6,,,Lärm. Lärmbekämpfung. Schallschutz. Filter (vgl.a.san 525),,
phy,205.9,,,Sonstiges,,
,,,,,,
,,Wärme. Statistische Physik (Temperaturstrahlung s. phy 495),,,,
,220,,Gesamtgebiet,,,
```

I would like to remove all rows where the second column (the numeric code) is empty.

In Open Refine I created a Facet->CustomizedFacet->FacetByBlank on the second column. In the appearing menu on the left, I clicked true (197 false, 2 true - which is correct). Then, I went to All->EditRows->RemoveAllMatchingRows. Instead of removing only the two rows, OpenRefine removes 143 rows and no data is shown anymore.

What has happend? And how can I remove only the two rows with an empty second column?

It might be connected to the row counter in the All column: The first time the entry in the first column "phy" is missing, there is no row count anymore.

```
1. phy 205.4 ...
2. phy 205.6 ...
3. phy 205.9 ...
             Wärme...
       220 ...
```

The 220 row does not contain the "phy" column and is incorrectly ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be operating in "record mode" as opposed to "row mode." If the facet says 197 true, 2 false, you should only see two rows displayed on the screen when you go to do your delete. If you see more than that try selecting Row mode.